# Could awaiting client.SendAsync(request) somehow cause code to block?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this two lines in my code, and I think they are causing my code to block, but I can't se how that would be possible. Sometimes when they are run, the rest of the code doesn't execute.

```
var paymentResponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
var paymentResponseMessage = await paymentResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I know it's bad practice, but the lines are only called in production, so I can't debug it.
Could these line cause my code to block?

Comment: yes, if you miss `await` somewhere in the method call chains. its better to have a go locally and set a debug breakpoints rather than guessing stuff.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to deadlock with `await` if you mix it with its synchronous siblings (i.e., `Task.Wait()`, `Task.Result`). See this for example: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: That's tough. If you don't even know what type of app is using the code.... I'm with @BagusTesa - indeed for particular types of apps calling `.Result`/`.Wait()` outside would cause deadlock (WinForms/WPF)... or some custom synchronization code combined with `.Result`... Without reasonable amount of details there is not much can be done about this - try to get an [mre].

Comment: This is a common problem when developers find there is an existing asynchronous method and they want to call it from synchronous code. This will cause the method to block like synchronous code, which isn't "bad" if that is what you are expecting, but sometimes they think that because it's `async` it's "faster background code". So as mentioned above, search the code for any/all calls of `.Result` or `Wait()`. Depending on what these methods do you could also trigger locks with things like databases set up for READ COMMITTED if these methods take a bit of time.

Comment: While you might not be able to debug, you're still able to log, wrap the code with a `StopWatch` and log the time elapsed (as a start).